# Summing items under a merged cell

Tags: excel, sum, cells, vba

I would like to ask help to sum all items under a merged cell.
Item looks like this:

```
       June  
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9  
2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1
```

June is a merged cell, and I want to sum all items under it. 
Is this even possible?

Comment: **Are the digits in separate cells or in a single cell??**

Comment: Yes it is possible. Start with [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist).

Answer (score 1):

This will work whether the cells are merged or un-merged.  Say we have merged **A1** through **C2** with contents like:

[image]

The following *UDF()* will give the sum of the numeric values:

```
Public Function InternalSum(rin As Range) As Double
   Dim v As String, CH As String, temp As String
   Dim dot As String, L As Long, i As Long
   Dim capture As Boolean
   v = rin(1).Text
   InternalSum = 0
   dot = "."
   temp = ""
   capture = False
   L = Len(v)
   If L = 0 Then Exit Function
   For i = 1 To L
      CH = Mid(v, i, 1)
      If IsNumeric(CH) Or CH = dot Then
         capture = True
         temp = temp & CH
         If i = L Then
            InternalSum = InternalSum + CDbl(temp)
         End If
      Else
         If capture Then
            capture = False
            InternalSum = InternalSum + CDbl(temp)
            temp = ""
         End If
      End If
   Next i
End Function
```

[image]

Note that both:

```
=internalsum(A1)
```

and

```
=internalsum(A1:C2)
```

will work.